# Update json object by adding new attribute in python

Tags: python, json

I'm new to python and json files and I have a json file which has only one attribute and I want to update each object in the file by adding a new attribute, my json file looks like:

```
[
{"marka": "تويوتا"},
{"marka": "شيفروليه"},
{"marka": "نيسان"}
]
```

and I want it to be something like:

```
[
{"marka": "تويوتا" , "tag" : "MANF"},
{"marka": "شيفروليه" , "tag" : "MANF"},
{"marka": "نيسان" , "tag" : "MANF"}
]
```

I tried this code but it gives me an error:

```
with open("haraj_marka_arabic.json", "r") as jsonFile:
     data = json.load(jsonFile)

tmp = data["tag"]
data["tag"] = "MANF"

with open("haraj_marka_arabic.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

The error I had is:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is a list of dictionaries (in Python speak), each containing the `'tag'` element, so you need to iterate through those list items and assign the new value to this `'tag'` key:

```
with open("haraj_marka_arabic.json", "r") as jsonFile:
     data = json.load(jsonFile)

for d in data:
    d["tag"] = "MANF"

with open("haraj_marka_arabic.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

your JSON file contains a list of dictionaries, to update each dict from your `data` list you can use:

```
for d in data:
    d['tag'] = "MANF"
```

then you can dump your `data` to a file:

```
with open("haraj_marka_arabic.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
### given this is your sample object (Dictionary):
  data = [
         {"marka": "تويوتا"},
         {"marka": "شيفروليه"},
         {"marka": "نيسان"}
         ]
##end of sample object (Dictionary)

with open("haraj_marka_arabic.json", "r") as jsonFile: ## Assume data contains the object (dictionary) above
     data = json.load(jsonFile)
```

your error is here: your data structure is an **array** (list) **of**  objects (**dictionaries**), you're accessing "skipping the **array** (list)"

```
for tmp in data:
 tmp["tag"] = "MANF"


with open("haraj_marka_arabic.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

Post edited to reflect the different terminology choice between Python and JSON.